# Database can't connect on live server and blank page is displayed, all fine on Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I am trying to setup a second instance of a website for testing purposes. I use the exact same files as the original version and all works fine when I test it on Xampp.

However, when I upload the files on the live server, something gets wrong. When the pages are loaded they appear as blank, there is no SQL error displayed, I tried this as well.

The code I use to connect to the DB is this one, if I remove it pages load correct, except that there is no DB connected. The DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME are all correct on live server as well:

```
$db = ADONewConnection('mysql'); 
$db->Connect(DBHOST,DBUSER,DBPASS,DBNAME) or die("Database not found! please install your application properly");
```

Also, all files in ADONewConnection library are fine, so it should be some setting on the live server that is different from Xampp and that I cannot think of.

I also tried this on another different hosting server and again no luck.

Any suggestions or ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Does your hosting company support ADOdb ?

The standard way to debug a blank page is looking at the error log or enable display_errors.

Comment: yes they do, it is being installed on the same hosting as the original website that works. Actually after two days I found the issue in the files_include.php file. It is being called from a file located in sub dir using `../` but it doesn't work because files_include is calling other files located in different sub dirs